# Why does new object in Linked List overwrite old object

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am creating a two-sided linked list. For that I implemented a Node with the following attributes:

```
struct Node {
public:
    int Daten;

    Node* Next = nullptr;
    Node* Last = nullptr;

    Node() {
    }

    Node(int Daten) {
        this->Daten = Daten;
    }
};
```

I then implemented a class, which adds Nodes to my Linked list.
I can add two Nodes to the list, and all the references work perfectly. As soon as I create an instance of the third Node, the programm assumes that I am trying to reference the second element in the linked list. This behaviour can be seen, because when I debug the code. The linked list works Perfectly with two elements, but as soon as I call the "Node" Class to create the third object of it, the second element gets overwritten by it.
This is the code on my Linked List Class.

```
class LList {
public:
    Node head;
    Node* NodePtr = &head;

    void AddNode(int Key) {
        if (NodePtr != &head) {
            Node newnode(Key);
            NodePtr = &head;
            NodePtr->Next = &newnode;
            newnode.Last = NodePtr;
            NodePtr = NodePtr->Next;
        }
        else {
            head.Daten = Key;
            NodePtr = nullptr;
        }
    }


    void printList() {
        std::cout << "List status now: ";
        Node* Localcopy = &head;
        while (Localcopy != nullptr) {
            std::cout << Localcopy->Daten << ", ";
            Localcopy = Localcopy->Next;
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

};
```

This is my main function where the code gets executed.

```
int main() {
    LList mytree;
    mytree.AddNode(7); // Works perfectly up to here.
    mytree.printList();
    mytree.AddNode(4); // Works perfectly up to here.
    mytree.printList();
    mytree.AddNode(2); // The first element points to the third Element, and the Second gets lost  or overwritten.
    mytree.printList();

    return 0;
}
```

The output I get is the following:

```
List status now: 7,
List status now: 7, 4,
List status now: 7, 2,
```

That is all which is inside of my project.
Why does this overwriting happen? Are there any mistakes that I am overlooking. How can I fix it?

Comment: Get rid of the use of `&` and replace it with new Node(). You end up storing pointers to local variables whos lifetime ends when the current function ends. This line is the problem: `NodePtr->Next = &newnode;` The `newnode` variable only exists in the if () {} scope but you keep a pointer to the node that no longer exists. Keeping a pointer to some object does not extend the object's lifetime.

Comment: This question should help: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope)

Comment: @drescherjm Do you propose that I store every single node of the linked list in the LList object, and then just write the references? How am I going to be able  to store the information of  the single Nodes, if you say that the information gets lost as soon as I leave my current scope.

Comment: ***Do you propose that I store every single node of the linked list in the LList object, and then just write the references?***  No, Not that unless your list would have a fixed maximum number of nodes then you could create some array of nodes and have your nodes point to elements in the array. Instead you most likely will need to use new to dynamically allocate nodes if you are required to create a list for your academic assignment.